# Word 2004 Timing Out Applescript on Find/Replace

Tags: macos, replace, ms-word, applescript

I am trying to run a find/replace through Applescript on a Word 2004 file. On an iMac, using OS 10.6.8.

Sample code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
activate
set myText to text object of selection
set myFind to find object of myText
clear formatting myFind
set italic of font object of myFind to true
set content of myFind to ""
clear formatting replacement of myFind
set content of replacement of myFind to "<I>^&</I>"
execute find myFind replace replace all
end tell
```

Every time I attempt to run this code, the script freezes the moment it gets to the "clear formatting ..." line. Applescript spits out the following error:

> error "Microsoft Word got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this (other than switching to Word 2008/2011, etc., as I am forced to work with 2004 for now)?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess... it looks like that line should have "of". You have "of" in a similar statement later in your code when you "clear formatting replacement".

```
clear formatting of myFind
```

If that doesn't work you can try...

```
tell myFind to clear formatting
```

Again, I am only guessing as I do not use Word.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get the same error with or without "of".

Comment: OK, that is weird. I tried your suggestion, 
'tell myFind to clear formatting'
and it seemed to run properly. I then tried to run it again later (same code!) and it failed.
Why would it only work part of the time?

Comment: It definitely appears to be hanging on "clear formatting." No matter which method I use, that part of the code is highlighted in the AppleScript after it times out.

After some more testing, unable to get the script to run anymore. It's not at all clear what prompted it to run correctly that one time.